# Unable to use `format = "latex"` in knitr::kable() within a rmarkdown document generated via shiny

Tags: r, shiny, knitr

I would love to use the `kableExtra` package features (as documented [here](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)) in the production of a PDF report from a Shiny app. Unfortunately, while I'm able to replicate the examples from the document linked above outside of a Shiny environment, I get the following error when I attempt it within Shiny:

> "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS report.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc2f0831607c9a.pdf --template "C:\Users\PStraforelli\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
>   ! Undefined control sequence.
>   l.160 \toprule
>
> pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
>   Warning: running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS report.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc2f0831607c9a.pdf --template "C:\Users\phil\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43
>   Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>   Stack trace (innermost first):
>       53: pandoc_convert
>       52: convert
>       51: rmarkdown::render
>       50: download$func [C:\Users\phil\Desktop\app/app.R#16]
>        1: shiny::runApp
>   Error : pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Here is a reproducible example:

The app.R file:

```
#From here: http://shiny.rstudio-staging.com/articles/generating-reports.html
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 32, 10),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(

      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
                tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
        file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

        params <- list(n = input$slider)

        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

The report.Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: pdf_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r}
#From here: http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:params$n, 1:6]

kable(dt, format = "latex", booktabs = T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped")
```
````

When I launch the app.R file onto an Internet browser, and click on "Generate report", I get the error quoted above. If I remove the `format = "latex"` argument within `knitr::kable()` in the `report.Rmd` file (and the `kable_styling()` function), than everything works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put `library(kableExtra)` in your rmarkdown. It will automatically load necessary LaTeX packages for you.

---

Update: rmarkdown render has some issues on clear up metadata. To ensure those packages are loaded, you can follow the direction in the "LaTeX packages used in this package" section of the vignette and put that `header-includes`in your yaml header.

See [Why does rendering a pdf from rmarkdown require closing rstudio between renders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080853/why-does-rendering-a-pdf-from-rmarkdown-require-closing-rstudio-between-renders/46083308#46083308) for details.

Comment: Hi Hao, thanks for very much for the prompt response, and I first want to say that the `kableExtra` package is awesome. I'm still getting an error even if I call the needed packages using `library()` (I updated my initial question accordingly), although it is somewhat different from my previous error message. It now starts with `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option H'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.139 \begin{table}[H]`.

Comment: Hmm... I restarted the R session, and ran again, and it now works fine. Thanks!

Comment: You reminded me something so I updated my answer. :)

Comment: Restarting the session worked for me as well